# Question about taking mouse input in unity 2D

Tags: unity, 2d, input, mouse

I'm learning a course on unity and when we started learning about taking mouse input the following code is used.

```
Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
pos.z = -Camera.main.transform.position.z;
pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
gameObject.transform.position = pos;
```

My problem is in the second line. Shouldn't our Z be 0 instead of minus wherever our camera is? Because the plane where we our designing our game is in z = 0, right?

Please go slow on me I'm still new to unity. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The z-coordinate given to ScreenToWorldPoint is the distance from the camera plane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html). If you set z to 0, the position returned will be in the camera's plane.

Is the ground plane at (0,0,0)? And the camera is at (0,0,-z) and pointing along the +z direction?

Comment: Aha, so it is -z relative to the camera?